# using picasso i am trying to set an image in imageview from the image path stored in database

Tags: android

I have stored the path of my images in sqlite database(eg R.drawable.img)how ever when i am trying to retrieve the image path and use it as the path for picasso i am not getting the image but the path is being displayed.

```
   //image is the column name for the path of image in database
    ImageView imageview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagetext);
    Context context = imageText.getContext();
    String path="image";
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(path)
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .resize(50,50)
            .into(imageview);
```

Comment: `R.drawable.img` is not path, it is ID. Are you sure it's exist?

Comment: I have my images in resource drawable folder. what is the write path/id to refer to it @StanislavBondar

Comment: Do you need to use `Picasso` and database for drawable id?

Comment: this is the only solution i can think of since i have about 300 small images. so you have any other solution??@StanislavBondar

Comment: You don't need to store and receive images with database 300 times. It's already stored at drawable folder. Use `imageView.setImageDrawable()`

Comment: its an picture dictionary app.how is it possible to get the particular image from drawable everytime user search for different words using setImageDrawable()@StanislavBondar

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the drawable id using its name, you can proceed as following:

`int id=getResources().getIdentifier(path,"drawable",getPackageName());`

And then use the id the way you want.

You can also try this to set directly the image to imageview

`imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),getResources().getIdentifier("image","drawable",getPackageName())));`

**PS:** you don't need Picasso for that I think.

Comment: how can i use that id to set the image in imageview??

Comment: test and let me know it works or not, so I can Imagine another aproach

Comment: it is still displaying the id that i have stored in database in imageview instead of the image.

Comment: the database is pre-loaded.i am developing a picture dictionary app.i just need to retrieve the data.

Comment: if you have already your IDs so just get the image using the id from db

Comment: imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),id));

Comment: instead of the path. Ensure the id is an integer

Comment: in the database what should be the datatype for the id?

Comment: the id should be an integer value.